# JSON faker for all combination

Tags: javascript, json, api, rest, faker

Currently I have a requirement of generating test data for a JSON schema. I have found this following github very useful for this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-schema-faker#overview

Now, if we want to extend it to generate all the required fields + all combinations of optional field, how can we generate this. For example:

The following JSON schema should output two JSON's:

```
{
    "title": "Example Schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "age": {
            "description": "Age in years",
            "type": "integer",
            "minimum": 0
        }
    },
    "required": ["name"]
}
```

---

```
{
    "name" : <random_string>
}
```

AND

```
{
    "name" : <random_string>,
    "age"  : <random_int>
}
```

Comment: You want class structure for it or something else

Comment: I want all combination for the json. For example, in JSON schema we can mention required fields. All other fields can be optional.

Answer (score 0):

You can try json-faker which is available in npm, it is easy to use